# How would i add a wallpapper/background image to a streamlit app? (still image)

Tags: background, streamlit

not sure how to add a background image to a streamlit app.
want to add a still image to the background of a streamlit app i am building, by still i mean the user being able to scroll down and have the image stay still in the background.

not sure how to do it and im learning to do coding using streamlit

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `your-image-url-here` with your image url

```py
st.markdown("""
    <style>
        .stApp {
        background: url("your-image-url-here");
        background-size: cover;
        }
    </style>""", unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Comment: Sweet thank u this helped heaps!

Comment: by "your URL here" do u mean the file directory or a website url? and sadly i couldnt get it to work